Сколько времени прошло после того как файл загрузили на сервер
if int(time.time() - os.path.getmtime(file)) > 43200:

Собственно, по истечению 12 часов, удаляю файл.
Возможно есть более практичный вариант это сделать?

Лучше записывать время и название файла в базу и делать из базы выборку файлов, которые нужно удалять. Дёргать файловый каталог каждый раз не очень хорошо, если у вас там очень много файлов будет.
